# PHPUnit: How to test cache properly in Symfony

Tags: laravel, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I have a method that gets info from the cache or (if the cache is empty) makes a long request to a 3rd-party service. I want to test my method to check that the data came from the cache of an external source.

In Laravel my code will look like this:

```
public function getExternalData($key)
{
    $response = Cache::get($key, null);

    if (!$response) {
        // heavy and complicated request
        $response = $this->externalSource->getData($key);

        Cache::set($key, $response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

and the test looks like this:

```
public function testFromCache($returnData)
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn($returnData);
}

public function testFromSource($returnData)
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn(null);

    $externalSourceMock = $this->partialMock(
        Source::class,
        function (MockInterface $mock) use ($returnData) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getData')->once()->andReturn($returnData);
        }
    );

    Cache::shouldReceive('set')->once()->andReturn(true);
}
```

Working with cache in Symfony seems a little bit different, so my code is like this:

```
public function __construct(
    private HttpClientInterface $client,
    private CacheInterface $cache,
    private LoggerInterface $logger
) {}

public function getExternalData($key)
{
    $responseDto = $this->cache->get($key, function () use ($key) {
        // heavy and complicated
        $response = $this->externalSource->getData($key);

        return $response;
    });
}
```

So the main question is: how can I write a similar test but for Symfony?

I also have other questions:

1. How can I test if there is data in the cache or not? Should I test it?
2. How can I test a callback function?
3. How can I mock the cache the right way?

Answer (score 0):

So, the first easy and more straight answer is: you never test the framework. In your case, you do not test if `Cache::set` or any similar method works, because you are testing if Laravel correctly coded if `Cache::xxxxxx` works, and yeah it works.

You want to test your own code, for example, call method `getUser()` and you want to make sure that it is using the cache if it exists, else it will call the database and cache it (this is just an example).

Following your questions:

1. As I said, you do not test if your data IS in the cache or not, but you test if the data is COMING from the cache or not
2. I am not sure what you are referring to this, share a concise example of what callback you want to test and we will help you
3. You can definitely mock the `Cache` facade, the idea of a `facade` is to be able to access an object in a different way, facade means something literally, google it and you will understand. Related to testing, that is the beautiful part of Laravel's implementation, if you have a facade whichever it is, you can do `YourFacade::shouldReceive('xxxx')` etc, and it will literally mock that part (you can also [spy](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html), `YourFacade::shouldHaveReceived('xxx')`, etc)